# yii2 dependant dropdown reset on edit action due to onchange function

Tags: yii2, onchange, cascadingdropdown

**Summary**

On edit action, a dropdown should display the existing value, but is being cleared by a (seemingly) unrelated onchange event.

**Details**

In a Yii2 form, I have 2 dependant dropdowns. make and model. The model dropdown is changes when the onchange event for make is fired.

```
<?php
    echo $form->field($model, 'make_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Make::find()->all(),'make_id','description'), 
        ['prompt'=>'-Choose a Make-',
        'onchange'=>'
            $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/equipmentmodel/selectlist?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                $( "select#equipmentmodel" ).html( data );
        });
    ']);
 ?>

 <?php
    echo $form->field($model, 'model_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(EquipmentModel::find()->all(),'model_id','description'),
        ['id'=>'equipmentmodel']
    );
 ?>
```

The updating of the model based on the make selection works fine.

I have now added a JS code that is triggered on the onchange event for the second dropdown, the model.

```
$script = <<< JS

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#equipment-make_id").change(function(){

        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="$laptopType"){
                $(".equipment_additional_attributes").not("#laptop_additional_attributes").hide();
                $("#laptop_additional_attributes").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="$desktopType"){
                $(".equipment_additional_attributes").not("#desktop_additional_attributes").hide();
                $("#desktop_additional_attributes").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".equipment_additional_attributes").hide();
            }
        });

        return false;

    }).change();
});

JS;

$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

The existence of this onchange event handler causes  $("#equipment-make_id") to be reset and I cannot see why. Removing all code from inside the handler, or even (only) returning false causes the reset of the value.

If I remove the event handler function from the source code, the value of the second dropdown remain intact.

The selected attribute for the option is set correctly, I can see this if I look at the page source code.

I need to retain the value of the second dropdown, but I am not sure how,

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was the existence of the additional change on the onchange handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#equipment-make_id").change(function(){
      // ...code here
    }).change();  // <=== THIS WAS causing the problem
});
```